# Zabbix and "PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 78 bytes)"

Tags: zabbix

I created this issue to solve a problem you have with zabbix, version 3.2 running on centos 7. The above error appeared when trying to access the zabbix GUI in a few moments.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You did not find anything about this error in the Internet? You haven't search, did you?

Answer (score 3):

I edited the `php.ini` file in CentOS as I saw here on stack overflow and it did not solve, it was necessary to edit the file `/etc/httpd/conf.d/zabbix.conf`, and modify the attribute `php_value memory_limit 128M` to **256M** or **512M**.

Comment: The value occurred twice in my version of /etc/httpd/conf.d/zabbix.conf. After changing them both and restarting, it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case:
You may reset filter settings by adding filter_rst=1 after ? symbol in php query.

For example:
https://your.zabbix.server.com/zabbix/latest.php?filter_rst=1

Answer (score 0):

First of all I had to find the file which contains the 'memory_limit' string by running this command:

```
grep -rnw '/etc' -e 'memory_limit'
```

Based on the result I increased the limit from 128M to 1024M in this below file:

```
/etc/opt/rh/rh-php72/php-fpm.d/zabbix.conf
```

Finally, restart the Apache, Zabbix, and PHP services:

```
systemctl restart rh-php72-php-fpm.service httpd zabbix-server
```